# How can i share a content on Google plus using OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus

How can I share content on Google plus using OAuth 2.0?
I'm looking for the URI to do this action (Posting data on the wall), for example :

> To get connected user info (https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo).
>   To search activities (https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities)
>   ...

But to share content to Google's stream (wall) I can't find the URI.
Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot post content programmatically to user's streams on Google+. You can [write app activities](https://developers.google.com/+/features/app-activities) using the [moments.insert](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert) method. On Google+ , user's always have control over what is shared to their stream.